# How to deal with cp932 encoding error trying to print the filename by file list

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-console

I am working on a script that randomly chooses a file and asks the user whether to execute it. I recently got the error shown below, and I'm confused about how to change my script to fix this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\randomplay.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(file)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u8138' in position 1: illegal multibyte sequence
```

The code below works in Python 2.x. However, I'm required to implement this function in Python 3.x. Can anyone advise me how to do it? I want to make it work the same as before.

```
import sys
import os,io
import random
import subprocess
import msvcrt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    indir = os.path.realpath("./")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(indir):
        random.shuffle(files)
        #print(files)
        for file in files:
            cmd="\""+file+"\""
            print(file)
            print("OK with it?")
            c = msvcrt.getch()
            print(str(ord(c)))
            if ord(c) == 27:
                exit()
            elif ord(c) == 13:
                print("executing...")
                subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
                exit()
            else:
                print("How about this?")
                pass
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I edit it right now

Comment: Are you sure it actually works in Python 2, or does `os.walk` return the filename with the character replaced by a "?" or "・" character? Python 2 defaults to the legacy ANSI file-system functions. The ANSI API uses a lossy encoding for unsupported characters. To list the original unicode filenames in Python 2, you have to use a `unicode` path, e.g. `os.walk(u".")`.

Comment: The simple solution for printing the original Unicode character is to upgrade to Python 3.6, which defaults to using the console's UTF-16 API. Or for older versions, including Python 2, pip install and enable the `win_unicode_console` module.

Comment: I upgrade to 3.6.x and it works! Thanks!  @eryksun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By @eryksun

By upgrading python to 3.6.X seems to be the most fast way to deal with this problem without change any script!
Now it works!

Thanks!